# Does a lead-to screen with AdSense ad conform to Google's rules?

Tags: google-adsense, search-results

Re: [Google's ad placement policy](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Placing_Google_ads_on_a_website_with_pop-ups)

I have noticed that when clicking on some Forbes links, I am taken to a screen with an ad in the middle - at the top there is a link to skip the ad.  Upon clicking on the skip link I am taken to the article I want to view.

I want to implement something similar on my sites, where, when clicking on a search result, a the results window first displays one AdSense add on the screen with a similar UI as what I saw on Forbes.

Currently, when a user clicks on a result, a new tab/window opens with the result.  What I am proposing is that before the result appears, the screen displays a "Continue to result" link at the top in large letters, and in the center of the page, "Advertisement" with the ad below.

This is the only popup that is user initiated and there are no other popups on the site.

Navigation elements are not modified in any way.

Will I get penalized by Google for implementing this?

Answer (score 2):

The term for a page that is in between you and the page you want to view is called an "interstitial".    Whether or not AdSense ads are allowed on interstitials was [discussed in the Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/4pDgpXUhMeo/lIu_Is8CPjwJ).   Many replies say that it is **not allowed** because of several restrictions in the Google Adwords terms of service:

> #### Site Behavior
>
> Sites showing Google ads should be easy for users to navigate. Sites may not change user preferences, redirect users to unwanted websites, initiate downloads, include malware or contain pop-ups or pop-unders that interfere with site navigation.
>
> Google ads, search boxes or search results may not be:
>
> - Placed on any non-content-based page.
> - Placed on pages published specifically for the purpose of showing ads.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adsense ads, they should be placed exclusively on pages that have content. This is the general rule.